# WordPress - Order posts by custom fields (PHP)

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I would like to order my posts primarily by 'start_date', and secondly by 'start_time' (for posts that have the same 'start_date'). I only know how to order one or the other. Please help!

[image: Image reference]

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of or off site links to code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). 
Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. This is so that we can try to reproduce the 
problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters Its documented

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/65769/multiple-orderby-values-in-wp-query Seek and ye shall find

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wordpress order posts by custom fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018140/wordpress-order-posts-by-custom-fields)

Answer (score 0):

try adding it after a comma,

```
=> 'start_date, start_time',
```